# MATLAB "Index out of bounds" Error

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a project to make FIR filter coefficients but when in process of Minimum-Order Lowpass Filter there is error which

[image]

I have no idea what that means and which part I need to repair:

```
function [ output_args ] = FIR_FilterCoeff()
N   = 100;        % FIR filter order
Fp  = 20e3;       % 20 kHz passband-edge frequency
Fp  = 20e3;       % 20 kHz passband-edge frequency
Fs  = 96e3;       % 96 kHz sampling frequency
Rp  = 0.00057565; % Corresponds to 0.01 dB peak-to-peak ripple
Rst = 1e-4;       % Corresponds to 80 dB stopband attenuation

NUM = firceqrip (N,Fp/(Fs/2),[Rp Rst],'passedge');

N2= 200; % change filter order to 200

NUM200 = firceqrip(N2,Fp/(Fs/2),[Rp Rst],'passedge');

Fst = 23e3; % transition width = Fst-Fp
NUM_MIN = firgr('minorder',[0,Fp/(Fs/2),Fst(Fs/2),1],[ 1 1 0 0 ],[Rp Rst]);
```

Comment: You should not paste error messages as pictures into your question. You should copy and paste their text directly into the question. Please see [ask] and [mcve] for tips on creating good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your error lies in `Fst(Fs/2)` on your last line. `Fst` is a vector of length 1. It has 1 value `23e3`. Round brackets, `()`, in MATLAB directly after a variable are used for [indexing variables](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

When you type `Fst(Fs/2)` you are attempting to access the `48000` element in `Fst` but it does not exist so MATLAB throws an error. I think you may have meant this to be

```
Fst/(Fs/2)
```

or (possibly)

```
Fst*(Fs/2)
```

The `*` sign is needed to perform multiplication in MATLAB. It is not good enough to simply use round brackets, `()`, as they have another purpose, [Matrix Indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).